# How would I split 'desandro masonry' columns by categories on a responsive wordpress layout

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design, categories

I have created a responsive 'pinterest style' layout on a wordpress blog. The tiles are created by the'featured images' functionality on the admin side. So when the user adds a featured image to their blog post, the 'featured image' will display on the home page integrated into a responsive masonry layout. so the effect on the homepage is a gallery of tiled images which act as blog post teasers. The images have a width of 100% within their respective column and a height of auto, so they retain their aspect ratio. On mobile the layout is single column, on tablet the layout is two columns wide and over 900px the layout is 3 columns wide. Bssically it works like this example http://tympanus.net/Development/GridLoadingEffects/index2.html but with 'featured images' which link through to their post.

I have 2 categories set up on my blog, let's say A and B. Within the layout described above ... On desktop view columns at 33.3% I would like the first column on the left to be populated with category A and the remaining 2 to be populated by category B and then on mobile where the column is single ... I would like the layout to be a default Masonry split, which would display alternate categories post thumbnails as you scroll down.

Does anyone have any idea on how this could be achieved ... or even if it can be achieved with Masonry?

here are a few snippets of the current setup

```
**//footer.php**

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/masonary.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
//Script to initialise Masonary
var content = document.getElementById('content');
var msnry = new Masonry( content );
imagesLoaded( content, function() {
    var msnry = new Masonry( content );
    console.log('all images are loaded');
    msnry.layout();
});
</script>

**//index.php - loop snippet**
<!-- Masonary content -->
<div class="masonry js-masonry" id="content">

                <!-- Start the Loop. -->
                <?php 
                // If have posts
                if (have_posts()) :

                // Loop through the post
                while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <!-- This adds the thumnails to the loop -->
    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && ! post_password_required() ) : ?>
        <!-- Masonry Item -->
         <div class="item">
            <!-- Overlay hover effect -->
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <span class="post-overlay clearfix">
                    <!-- Post title to appear on hover -->
                    <h2 class="overlay"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <!-- Post Thumbnail to appear in Masonry grid -->
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </span><!--End of hover-title-->
            </a>
        </div><!--End of item-->

        <!-- End the while loop -->
                <?php endwhile;?>

</div><!--End of .masonary-->

**//style.css   - masonry css snippet**
img { 
  max-width: 100%; 
  height: auto !important; 
}

**//mobile**
.masonry {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.masonry .item {
  position: relative;
  width:  100%;
  float: left;
  padding: 15px;
}

**//tablet**
.masonry .item {
        width:  50%;
    }

**//Desktop**
.masonry .item {
        width:  33%;
    }
```

thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use Isotope, which has built in sorting functions which you could use?

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/sorting.html

Not sure it does exactly what you want, as it will still lay them out out in a row first. But you could add a data-attribute to each post which spits out a number to order them by.

```
Post 1 data-order: 1 cat: A
Post 2 data-order: 2 cat: B
Post 3 data-order: 3 cat: A
Post 4 data-order: 4 cat: B
```

Then it will make them appear to be Cat A on the left, B on the right at desktop, but alternate on a single column mobile view. Quite a hack, but it might work?